# Access navigation pane from stacked page

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm new to `Blackberry Cascades` and I want to create a simple `NavigationPane`. I'm very used to Qt's [`StackView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html) which allouse you to push and pop pages to and from the stack. However, Qt's `[StackView][1]` has this attached property called [`Stack.view`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stack.html#view-attached-prop) which allows you to access the stack from any child page.

How can I do this in Blackberry's Cascades? Is it possible to access the [`NavigationPane`](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__navigationpane.html) stack of pages from the current page you're in? I see this extremely useful.

For example I have this simple project with two qml files each representing one page:

Main page:

```
// main.qml
import bb.cascades 1.4
NavigationPane {
    id: nav
    Page {
        Container {
            ListView {
                dataModel: XmlDataModel {
                    source: "data.xml"
                }
                onTriggered: {

                    if (indexPath.length > 1) {
                        var chosenItem = dataModel.data(indexPath);
                        var contentpage = itemPageDefinition.createObject();

                        contentpage.itemPageTitle = chosenItem.name
                        nav.push(contentpage);
                    }
                }
                accessibility.name: "Listing"
            }

        }

    }
    attachedObjects: [
        ComponentDefinition {
            id: itemPageDefinition
            source: "ItemPage.qml"
        }
    ]
    onPopTransitionEnded: {
        page.destroy();
    }
}
```

Secondary page:

```
// ItemPage.qml
import bb.cascades 1.4

Page {
    property alias itemPageTitle: titlebar.title

    titleBar: TitleBar {
        id: titlebar
    }

    content: Container {
    }
}
```

Is it possible to access `nav` or `NavigationPane` from `ItemPage.qml`? I would like e.g. to create a new page from `ItemPage.qml` and push it on the stack. Is it possible to do so?

**EDIT:**

For example there is [this](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/ui/navigation/multiple_screens_stack.html) documentation page on the Blackberry developers website which has this example with a main page:

[image]

and a secondary page:

[image]

As you can see, in the secondary `myPage.qml` he uses the `navigationPane`. How is that possible? How does he have access to an ID present in another component?

Comment: You always have access to NavigationPane through its ID if i remember correctly

Comment: @BojanKogoj You are right! Just figured this out. However I didn't find this explicitly documented anywhere...